# How to check key value is exist in an array using PHP

Tags: php

I need to check some key value is exist in an array using PHP. Here is my code:

```
$comment = json_encode(array(array('day_id' => '1', 'comment' => 'vodka0'),array('day_id' => '', 'comment' => ''), array('day_id' => '3', 'comment' => 'vodka3'),array('day_id'=>'4','comment'=>'hytt')));
$arrComment = json_decode($comment, true);
```

Here I need to check some `day_id` key has value or all `day_id` key has blank value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to check this:

```
// extract all day_id columns
$dayId = array_column($arrComment, 'day_id');
// filter the empty values
$filtered = array_filter($dayId);

if (empty($filtered)) {
  echo "All Day Ids are empty.";
}
else {
  echo "Some or all of them have some value.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this: `var_dump(array_column($arrComment, 'day_id'));`

It returns all values of `day_id` key. Now do what you want.

Comment: I need to check this inside `if...else` statement.

Comment: Ok above code will provide you array of `day_id` values. Now filter your array with `$someVar = array_filter($values)`. `array_filter()` removes empty value. If all are empty `$someVar` variable will be empty. Hope you got your answer. I can give you idea and you get your hints. Now write your code. You'll get expected output. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrComment); $i++) {
    if (isset($arrComment[$i]['day_id'])) {
        //value is set
    } else {
        //value is not set
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.